# How to authorize access to the application path?

Tags: uwp

I want to create a file `mytest.txt` in my UWP app, but I always get the exception

> UnauthorizedAccessException access to the path is denied

When I call:

```
string destinationPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "mytest.txt");
FileStream fs = File.Create(destinationPath);
```

I tried with `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` too and get the same exception. I'm also debugging my app in Visual Studio opened with `Run as administrator`.

Note: This is actually a UWP app with Xamarin.Forms, but I don't think that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a file in UWP can be done with the following code:

```
// Create sample file; replace if exists.
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("mytest.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files